# Use Hardware RX pin as an interrupt pin of arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, serial-port, interrupt, avr

I want to use hardware RX pin of Arduino as interrupt pin. If there is any data available on RX pin, an interrupt signal will be generated, call a callback function to read incoming serial data.I don't want my loop() function constant reading on serial port. I am using this code but my interrupt is not triggered.I also tried by removing digitalPintointerrupt() but getting no response.

```
`#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
const byte interruptPin = 0;//In arduino MEGA RX 19. TX 18
String msg = "";//Incomming message
#define Line_RX 3 //UART RX
#define Line_TX 2 //UART TX

SoftwareSerial mySerial (Line_TX, Line_RX); //initialize software serial

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(19200);
  mySerial.begin(19200);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin), serial_read, HIGH);
}//end setup

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}//end loop

void serial_read(){

  char _bite;
  sei();//Disable hardware interrupts for a moment
  while(Serial.available()>0){
    delay(1);//Do not delete this delay
    if(Serial.available()>0){
      _bite = (char)Serial.read();
      msg += _bite;
      if(_bite == '\n'){
       mySerial.print(msg);//Do what you print your message
        msg = "";//Clean message for new one
        break;
      }//end if
    }//end if
  }//end while
  cli();//re-enabling hardware interrupts
}//en
```

d serial_read`

Answer (score 0):

`sei()` ENABLES interrupts, while `cli()` disables them.  Your comments suggest you have them backwards.  Perhaps there are other problems, but these instructions are certainly not consistent with your intentions.

If you want to get lower-level, consider a pure interrupt-driven design like:

```
ISR (USART0_UDRE_vect)
{
    // Send next byte and increment pointer
    UDR0 = *ub_outptr++;
    // Pointer wrapping
    if (ub_outptr >= UART_buffer + BUFF_SIZE)
    ub_outptr = UART_buffer;
    // If buffer is empty: disable interrupt
    if(--ub_buffcnt == 0)
    UCSR0B &= ~(1 << UDRIE0);
```

}

I know this takes you out of the Arduino library stuff, so this may not be ideal for you.  But it works (the example is for sending data, as I have an active project where the microcontroller sends data to an LCD display.  Just an example in AVR-GCC C.)

Comment: I have written a print statement at the beginning but i am not able to enter the callback function. If i use software serial (pin 2,3 as TX,RX) and use it as interrupt pin, then  callback function called 2 times for every byte. but i am not able to call callback function with hardware serial

Comment: I'm not sure how to direct you to proceed.  I design bare-metal designs more often than Arduino-based designs.  But a quick look at your code and the `cli` and `sei` instructions with comments that imply the exact opposite grabbed my notice, that's all.  All my serial designs use interrupt-based transmit and receive as shown in my edited answer.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I have to write cli() to disable the interrupt. But still i am not able to call my callback function. If i use software serial, pin no (2,3) as tx and rx, then i am able to call my callback function.

Answer (score 0):

Try my [NeoHWSerial](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoHWSerial).  It is a modified version of the Arduino core class, `HardwareSerial`, the class used for `Serial`, `Serial1`, etc.  It adds the ability to register a callback for each received character.